# JXA NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError exception

Tags: javascript, macos, javascript-automation

I'm using the following JXA (JavaScript for Automation) code on OS/X 10.11.5:

```js
function createFolder(path, createIntermediateDirectories) {
    var error = {}
    $.NSFileManager.defaultManager
        .createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(
            $(path).stringByStandardizingPath, 
            createIntermediateDirectories, 
            null, 
            error);
    if (error)
        throw Error("Could not create folder '" + path + "'");
};
```

I get an error when running this, although it actually does create the folder. Here's the error:

> Error: exception raised by object: -[NSNull objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff7b69b780 (-2700)

Judging by the fact that the folder is actually created, and the text of the error message, I'm assuming the issue is with the "attributes" parameter, which is null (nil). I figure that it creates the folder, then goes to assign the attributes, and that's when it fails.

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this? I haven't had any trouble calling any of the other NSFileManager methods from JXA, including those to which I pass null and/or boolean values, so this has be stumped.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry,
I don't have much time now, so here is a quick solution that works fine here:

```
function createFolder(path, createIntermediateDirectories) {
    error = $()

    $.NSFileManager.defaultManager.createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError(
        $(path).stringByStandardizingPath, 
        createIntermediateDirectories, 
        $(), 
        error)

    if (error) {
        $.NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
    }
};
```

Have fun!
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: That keeps it from throwing an exception, which is awesome! Thanks. And if I check the result for true or false, that seems to be reliable. However, I can't seem to do a anything with "error". It's always "truthy", but there doesn't seem to be any properties I can use to report the error (which would be "Already Exists" or something like that, in my test case). So the problem is solved (thank you very much), and now I just have a little puzzle.

Comment: I think the createDirectoryAtPathWithIntermediateDirectoriesAttributesError returns always true if the given directory is available after the call. The only thing I found to throw an error was to create a text file named identically like the directory you want to create.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.